# Small Business Email Server Internal vs External DNS IP

Tags: networking, email, dns

I am not in charge of the network, but I have responsibility for the Email Server at my workplace. We outsource networking, and how it was set is like this:

**Mail Server** (192.168.0.2)

**Internet Firewall** (155.x.y.z)

**Internal DNS Server** (mail.example.com -> 192.168.0.2)

**Public DNS (World)** (mail.example.com -> 155.x.y.z)

If i ping 155.x.y.z from within my LAN 192.168.0.0/24, I do not get a reply. When I consulted my network team, they said that I was not able to access 155.x.y.z from within the 192.168.0.0/24.

**Problem**
My users use laptops, when they come into the LAN, for a while they still have (mail.example.com -> 155.x.y.z) in their DNS cache, and thus cannot get any reply from the mail server.

The options I have used are using a shorter TTL, but it has not worked because some of it is being overridden.

How can I fix the above?

Comment: Windows? Flush the DNS cache `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: @DavidPostill many executive users use this setup, day in day out. Hard to tell them to run a `cmd` daily.

Comment: You can probably automate it ...

Comment: Smart, maybe a windows service which they run when they come into the network...or even detects network change and runs itself, smart...make it an answer :D

Comment: Not enough meat for an answer. When you figure it out you can answer your own question :)

Comment: Tell them that to fix the issue, they just need to reboot once; that'll clear the DNS cache.

Comment: The network design seems broken by design, it should be repaired. Workarounds are just that: Workarounds. Not solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is equipment capable of providing `NAT loopback` or `hairpin NAT` which allows the public IP to be accessible from within your LAN.

This is usually only available on business-grade network equipment so you'll have two options - buy a better router or try and flash your router with a firmware such as DD-WRT etc.

Comment: Oh I see, so that is in the network place of things, can I ask, is this what enterprise-grade networks employ?

Comment: "is this what enterprise-grade networks employ?"  Yes.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I see thanks. Will read this up to give me some info, probably might not implement for reason of the size of department. But Thanks!

Comment: A couple hundred pounds could get you an entry - level solution.